# Version Python 2.7.6 by default in Ubuntu

Tags: python

What minimum version of Ubuntu comes with Python 2.7.6 by default? ¿Ubuntu 14.04 has Python 2.7.6 by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see all the in updated* versions of Ubuntu: http://packages.ubuntu.com/python2.7

```
precise (12.04LTS) (python): Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
2.7.3-0ubuntu3.8 [security]: amd64 i386
2.7.3-0ubuntu3 [ports]: armhf powerpc

precise-updates (python): Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
2.7.3-0ubuntu3.8: amd64 armhf i386 powerpc

trusty (14.04LTS) (python): Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2 [security]: amd64 i386
2.7.6-8 [ports]: arm64 armhf powerpc ppc64el

trusty-updates (python): Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el

wily (python): Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
2.7.10-4ubuntu1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el

xenial (python): Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
2.7.11-7ubuntu1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x

yakkety (python): Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
2.7.12~rc1-2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x
```

<sub>* By updated I mean that they have had updates applied. Ancient versions of install media may ship older versions but they are likely the same point release, just an updated or patched build.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.10 was the first version of Ubuntu to ship with Python 2.7.6 by default. Ubuntu 15.04 came with Python 2.7.8; Ubuntu 15.10 came with Python 2.7.9; and Ubuntu 16.04 has Python 3.5.1.

Source: Distrowatch https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu